# How to get uploaded file in Node.js Express app using angular-file-upload

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I want to upload a file using angular-file-upload. But when I try to access `req.body.files` or `req.files` i get `undefined`.

Can anybody tell me how to get the file which is uploaded through angular-file-upload in node.js express app ?

Request Payload is as below:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myFile"; filename="BroadcomLogo.gif"
Content-Type: image/gif
```

JS Code:

```
$scope.upload[index] = $upload.upload({
   url : '/upload',
   method: 'POST',
   file: $scope.selectedFiles[index],
   fileFormDataName: 'myFile'
});
```

Node Code

```
upload: function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.files);
    res.send("Hello");
},
```

Comment: please provide some of your code examples, particularly server side node.js code

Comment: As i have already mentioned req.files is undefined

Answer (score 8):

You need to use a middleware that parses files from a request in Node.js:

```
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var multipartMiddleware = multipart();
app.post('/upload', multipartMiddleware,upload);
```

> Simply put, **middleware are functions that handle requests**. A server
>   created by connect.createServer can have a stack of middleware
>   associated with it. When a request comes in, it is passed off to the
>   first middleware function, along with a wrapped ServerResponse object
>   and a next callback. **Each middleware can decide to respond by calling
>   methods on the response object, and/or pass the request off to the
>   next layer in the stack by calling next()**.
>
> http://stephensugden.com/middleware_guide/

In the case of the multipart middleware, it will call the next() method so you can write your own function to respond to the request.

Of course you need to install it first: `npm install connect-multiparty`

They are other middlewares that handle multipart uploads:

- [busboy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/busboy#readme) and [connect-busboy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-busboy#readme)
- [multiparty](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multiparty#readme) and [connect-multiparty](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-multiparty#readme)
- [formidable](https://www.npmjs.org/package/formidable#readme)
- [multer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multer#readme)

You should probably use one that is compatible with connect, as express is built on top of connect

Comment: `express.multipart` is gone in Express 4+

Comment: So is `express.bodyParser`. See [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x).

Comment: It throws me a error Most middleware are not bundled with express

Comment: Ok, right, I have updated again. I never worked with express 4 for now (which seems to be very new)

Comment: I figured out that the app structure i copied from somewhere   was using json body parser so i removed json body parser and it worked

Answer (score -4):

Access it in the `files` object with the `name` attribute as the key:

```
req.files.myFile
```